# Keeping track of which button was pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I have 2 buttons, when clicked on they lead to the same window. But, I want to be able to keep track of which button was pressed so I can do different things based on that, below is how I have them defined:

```
<div class = "buttons">
     <button class = "worldBtn" onclick="window.location.href='map/map.html';">WORLD</button>
     <br>
     <button class = "usBtn" onclick="window.location.href='map/map.html';">UNITED STATES</button>
</div>
```

Is there any way I will be able to achieve that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a URL query parameter to distinguish them.

```
<div class = "buttons">
     <button class = "worldBtn" onclick="window.location.href='map/map.html?loc=world';">WORLD</button>
     <br>
     <button class = "usBtn" onclick="window.location.href='map/map.html?loc=us';">UNITED STATES</button>
</div>
```

Then in `map.html` the JavaScript can check `window.location.search` to determine which button was used.

Answer (score 1):

add one same class to button on click using $(this)  you get it value attribute.
here is a small code snippet

```js
 
$(".btn").click(function(e){
var title=$(this).attr("value");
alert(title);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "buttons">
     <button class = "worldBtn btn" onclick="window.location.href='map/map.html';" value="WORLD">WORLD</button>
     <br>
     <button class = "usBtn btn" onclick="window.location.href='map/map.html';" value="UNITED STATES">UNITED STATES</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the click event to track which button was clicked and act accordingly

HTML

```
<div class = "buttons">
     <button id="btn1" class = "worldBtn">WORLD</button>
     <br>
     <button id="btn2" class = "usBtn">UNITED STATES</button>
</div>
```

Javascript using JQuery

```
$('#btn1').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log('worldBtn clicked');
   window.location.replace("map/map.html");
})

$('#btn2').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log('usBtn clicked');
   window.location.replace("map/map.html");
})
```